# Парсинг математических выражений

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток! Задача - написать ф-цию, которая получает строку с мат. выражением,
например: 1 + 8 * 3 и должна вернуть результат. Можно ли выполнять операции с числами, не прибегая к конструкциям, типа:

```
switch($sign) {
   case '+':
     $numbers[1] + $numbers[2]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = "1 + 8 * 3";
$result = eval($str);
```

Comment: @dimka3210, не самое лучшее решение, если математический пример будет введен любым пользователем.

Comment: от пользователя вообще любых подлянок можно ждать. Но тут в задании этого нет.

Answer (score 1):

[Обратная польская нотация](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C).

Comment: и как это относится к моему вопросу?

Comment: Это теоретическая часть по языковым анализаторам. В простейшем случае - парсер математических выражений.

Answer (score 1):

[Вот](http://www.cip-labs.net/2011/11/21/ipsum-the-php-formula-parser/) неплохой парсер, для тех кому использование eval нежелательно или требуется дополнительные математические функции.